# Retrieve integer value from Database using PHP

Tags: php

I'm increment an ID from my code. When I retrieve the maximum value from database it does't assign to the variable.

I test my query from database SQL then it shows the maximum value. but when I echo it doesn't show.

Here is my code,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="test_issue.php">
           <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="submit"  /> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    include ("connection.php");
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {               
                    // $queryselect =  "SELECT issued_id FROM pass WHERE pass_id=8";
                    $queryselect= "SELECT MAX(issued_id) FROM pass WHERE status='Issued'";
                    $last_sec_result = mysqli_query($connection,$queryselect );

                    if($last_sec_result!=0)
                    {
                        $last_sec_value = mysqli_fetch_array($last_sec_result);
                        $sec_id_no = $last_sec_value['issued_id'];
                        echo $sec_id_no;   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo $last_sec_result ;
                        echo "database query failed please check data you enter.";
                    }
                    // echo $sec_id_no;
            }
?>
```

When I retrieve value with a simple select query (`SELECT issued_id FROM pass WHERE pass_id=8`) it shows the value. I'm stuck with this. Can anyone help me Please.

Comment: what does  `echo $sec_id_no;` give

Comment: its on the page. I just echo to check whether value was passed or not.

Comment: did you try `var_dump();`?

Comment: yes It shows null.

Comment: @M.Hemant it shows value when use var_dump but when I echo it doesn't show the value.

Comment: check your query(SELECT MAX(issued_id) FROM pass WHERE status='Issued') to direct run in phpmyadmin it return records or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- mysql_query() doesn't return an integer as your condition is waiting for
2- use alias to be sure about the index in the returned result set

```
include ("connection.php");
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {               
                // $queryselect =  "SELECT issued_id as issued_id FROM pass WHERE pass_id=8";
                $queryselect= "SELECT MAX(issued_id) as issued_id FROM pass WHERE status='Issued'";
                $last_sec_result = mysqli_query($connection,$queryselect );

                if($last_sec_result !== null)
                {
                    $last_sec_value = mysqli_fetch_array($last_sec_result);
                    $sec_id_no = $last_sec_value['issued_id'];
                    echo $sec_id_no;   
                }

                else
                {
                    echo $last_sec_result ;
                    echo "database query failed please check data you enter.";
                }
                // echo $sec_id_no;
        }
```

Comment: I converted by using ```(int)$variable``` then it shows 0 but the value is not zero.

Comment: SELECT MAX(issued_id) as issued_id FROM pass WHERE status='Issued', run this query directly in phpmyadmin or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Your query defines column `MAX(issued_id)` without alias, so, in fetched record it has some fancy name like... well, `MAX(issued_id)`.

Try to change your query like this (note `AS issued_id` part):

```
SELECT MAX(issued_id) AS issued_id FROM pass WHERE status='Issued'
```

This will make sure fetched record has`issued_id` field, and your following code will be able to extract it.

Answer (score 0):

So if previous answers do not give you an expected solution then
there are no rows with status set to exact same content `'Issued'`,
that is why query return empty result array.

```
SELECT issued_id, status FROM pass;
# must return some rows

SELECT MAX(issued_id) AS issued_id FROM pass;
# must return some numbers

SELECT MAX(issued_id) AS issued_id FROM pass WHERE status='Issued';
# should return expected value
```